# Keyboard limited key stops working sometime

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

Basically, I'm having a problem with the keyboard keys since the second last row occasionally gets stuck while typing. I've already gone through other previously asked questions that may have a similar issue to mine.

I discovered one usage command that is useful for a short amount of time. When I execute this command, the keyboard stops becoming stuck and resumes normal operation for a short period of time, but the next day it will require the same thing.

Is there a lasting solution?

For the temporary solution, I'm using

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: Personally I'd recommend replacing the keyboard rather than looking for a software solution for your *unstated* release of Lubuntu.